# how to depoly/upload laravel project on bluehost

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, shared-hosting

i have laravel project that is ready to deploy,

i need to deploy it on blue host,

i searched so many times about this but could not find clear answer,

so could you please guide me to deploy this laravel project ?

Comment: Do you have a test environment that you can practice a deployment on? What specifically are you stuck on? Could you Rsync or SFTP it into place, and then run any initialisation scripts when it is synced? Bear in mind that your build process depends on what build process you have chosen, so you'll be the best judge of how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for asking that. Please, Ignore those who don't understand the pain of not having AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying so many methods, I have managed to deploy a Laravel 5.1 application to a shared hosting. Hope this will save you some time. The following steps are tried and tested in 1and1 dedicated hosting server.

You should have SSH access to the server to install composer and some artisan commands.

Installing composer:

Connect to your server via ssh.

1and1 instances have multiple versions of php installed. Laravel needs at least php version 5.5.29. So you can check the available php versions. php5.5 should be good enough for rest of the steps.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep php
$ php5.5 -v
PHP 5.5.33 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Mar 8 2016 15:42:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Go to the desired directory (Normally the website’s root directory). Download the composer installer.

```
$ wget https://getcomposer.org/installer
$ php5.5 installer
```

Now you can see a file composer.phar downloaded to the current directory. This should be used for all composer activities.

Upload the source code (or clone from repository) to this directory. (Don’t forget to modify your .env file)
Edit the artisan file and scripts part of composer.json file to change all references of php to php5.5

Run the below command to perform composer install.

```
$ php5.5 composer.phar install
```

Run the below command to perform db migrate.

```
$ php5.5 artisan migrate
```

Replace all the lines in the /public/.htaccess with the below:

```
RewriteBase /public/

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

At this point your laravel application should be up and running on http://yourdomain.com/public. You can modify your website root to point to /public to remove public from the URL.

Comment: Thanks for ur response , but i have completed laravel project , can i upload project's folder directly to bluehost's public folder ?

Comment: Ya you can directly upload and you have do all the migrations and other needed things as such as you have done in the local host while development.

Comment: Either via FTP or you can directly zip the project in the local and upload it in the public folder and then extract it over there. Ensure that the `APP_KEY` is present in the `.env` file.

Comment: @Abdulelah.k. If so you find my answer is matching your request you can +1 upvote or make it as correct answer since it may be useful for the other developers who get this doubt inorder to solve it. Thanks :)

Comment: sure, thank you for sharing experience

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful. I shocked that no one up-voted it yet.